# How to Display Right Result

Tags: sql, sql-server

If you have the data with this list:

```
nvarchar  int    int    nvarchar   nvarchar
Line      start  end    typ        color
-------------------------------------------
T11       1      null   cookie     Blue
T11       null   10     cookie     Blue
T11       null   null   cookie     Blue
T11       null   null   cookie     Blue
T2        20     null   computer   Red
T2        null   null   computer   Red
T2        null   52     computer   Red
T3        null   null   dark       black
T3        52     null   dark       black
T3        null   10     dark       black
```

The requested result should be:

```
Line      start  end    typ        color
-------------------------------------------
T11       1      10     cookie     Blue
T2        20     52     computer   Red
T3        52     10     dark       black
```

How should I do it in SQL server 2012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for.  Obviously replace tablename with the name of your table.

```
SELECT t.line, MIN(t.START), MAX(t.END), t.typ, t.color
FROM dbo.tablename t
GROUP BY t.line, t.typ,  t.color
```